# Service bootup android forced stopped at boot- What to do?

Tags: android, service, boot

I want to start a service at bootup. 
I've done a breoadcast receiver, started a service from broadcastreceiver, all inserted in xml.
The tutorial from `http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/` helped me a lot.

The result:
On emulator, as on real device happens like this:
- service is started and then immediately stopps!
I don't know why the service stops!

The service is started for sure, I can read logs and toast msg. that certifies the service is started.

Also in logs I can see some msg like:

```
<u>
05-17 23:18:44.379: D/EAS SyncManager(247): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
05-17 23:18:44.789: D/EAS SyncManager(247): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
05-17 23:18:44.860: D/EAS SyncManager(247): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
05-17 23:18:44.999: D/My Service(258): starting broadcast receiver
05-17 23:18:45.119: D/My Service(258): starting service in onCreate
05-17 23:18:45.985: D/Eas Debug(247): Logging: 
05-17 23:18:45.999: D/EAS SyncManager(247): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
05-17 23:18:46.299: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): Attempting to allocate 998 KB for FAT
</u>
```

The EAS SyncManager is destroyed. I belive this is the cause why my service is forced stopped. 
From what I've read from http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/exchange/SyncManager.java.html it seams that when EAS SyncManager is destroyed, the started service on boot, receives a StopSelf() by default.

I don't know if this is true or not.
And if it is true... how can I fix it?
Does anyone confrunted with this until now?
Please help.

here is the code:

class of

// class of service

```
public class Contacts_Service extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        Log.d("My Service", "onCreate");

        mPeriodicEventHandler = new Handler();      
                mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask,13000);
    }



     private Runnable doPeriodicTask = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {

                //your action here
                Log.d("My Service", "eeeevery 13000 ms");



                mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, 13000);
            }
        };

}
```

// BroadcastReceiver class from where is lunched the service on boot

```
public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())){

         Log.d("My Service", "starting broadcast receiver");
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction("com.Srv.mail.Contacts_Service");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);

            //serviceIntent.setAction("com.Srv.mail.SrvMailSettingsActivity");
            //context.startActivity(serviceIntent);

    }

    }

}
```

and also the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Srv.mail"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


 <receiver android:name=".MyStartupIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="Contacts_Service">
                <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.Srv.mail.Contacts_Service" />
            </intent-filter>
            </service>  






        <activity
            android:name="com.Srv.mail.SrvMailSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!-->intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter-->

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the service ?

Comment: If your service is an `IntentService` it is likely that after processing the `Intent`, it stops itself with `stopSelf().` Tough to say without looking at your code.

Comment: the service shouldn't stop itself, it should run a thread and repeat thread at 13000 ms, the service should remain active and should be seen in Running services.

When I lunch it from an activity.... no problem, service start, runs every 13000 ms.
but when run at startup from broadcastreceiver ... it runs and then stops itself.

don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure Just try this too.. May be it works

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
// Your code
}
```

Comment: nope, no result, replace code with your if part,  the same thing. service crashes, starts and after stops, can't see it in Running services

Other suggestions? does anyone encountered this problem? Am I the only one that starts a service at startup?

Comment: somehow it has solved by itself.
In the emulator I run the above script, service is stopped by itself as described.
Then, I run another project on the same emulator, the application started(I installed a widget).Restart Emulator and after restart emulator, the boot up service didn't stop anymore. It remains active!

On real device, service is stopping itself, installation of new app has no effect, same thing service stop by itself.

Comment: so at the end ... I used a widget with no view and stared the service from the widget. Building it like this ... assures me that my service will start at bootup.